Ansible - play using pyATS fails "show: not found\"
I am fairly new to ansible automation
I have created a playbook to run the command "show ip interface brief" on a cisco switch and then parse the output with pyATS (and then print it out)
But when I run the play it fails saying the following:
fatal: [IP removed]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "/bin/sh: 1: show: not found\n", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

This is my playbook:
---
- name: pyats parsing test
  hosts: switches
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: show ip int br with pyats
    ansible.utils.cli_parse:
      command: "show ip interface brief"
      parser:
        name: ansible.netcommon.pyats
      set_fact: sh_ip_int_parsed

  - debug:
      var: sh_ip_int_parsed


Note - I have run other playbooks on this switch/host group fine with the cisco.ios.ios_command module
I only get this error when trying to use pyATS (this is the only output parser I've tried)

Stumbled upon the same, there is a bug in ansible utils which is fixed but not yet in the version you get if you install it via pip:
https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.utils/pull/357
